# How to access wso2 published api from angular application

Tags: angular, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an angular application that have been working perfectly, but now I have a requirement to put my backend in WSO2 for security purposes.

I have been looking in different repositories and stackoverflow questions, I found some angular packages but didn't find any tutorial to help me.

I am using angular 16 and WSO2 API manager 3.2.0

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the requirement? What I understood is that you have an API published in the WSO2 API Manager, and trying to access that particular API from your Angular Application. If that is the case, you have to configure your Angular to generate an Access Token from the APIM by calling the Token Endpoint and then invoking the required API using any REST API libraries from your Angular. You can follow this for more info: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/consume-api/invoke-apis/invoke-apis-using-tools/invoke-an-api-using-the-integrated-api-console/